# Insert record into table, if foreign key doesnt exist insert also into another

Tags: mysql, database

I have created this database:

[image: database]

and I want to insert data into it.

Those data will come from array and will always be `ad_system, ad_campaing, ad_group, keyword, impressions, click, price, conversion`.

I think the structure of DB is good. But my app purpose is only to load report data, format them and then save them into DB. So for example I will load first report, and I would want to insert It into DB. That means I need to probably check if foreign key exists in another table(because I am mainly inserting only in `Report` table, and then insert it into that table and so on ? Is that possible ? and is that right approach ? it seems kinda weird but right.

Comment: Yes, your schema clearly shows that Report depends on Keyword, so you have to find an existing or insert a new Keyword record first.  But to do that, you have to find or insert a Group record, and so on for every other table, since the dependency chain goes all the way back to System.

Comment: Yea, and thats the problem. Because what I have to do is only load reports and save them into DB. So It looks like every time I will load a report with new  `ad_sytem, ad_campaing or ad_group` I need to first insert those records... As I think about it, that means I always have to go from top(`ad_system`) and check if that value exists, if not insert it, and go all the way down to `report` table, is that right ?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.  Seems like extra work, I know, but to conform to a 3rd-normal-form schema, that's what has to happen.